# What type should I use to document ES6 module parameters in jsdoc?

Tags: ecmascript-6, jsdoc, es6-modules, jsdoc3

Let's say I import an [ES6 module](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/08/es6-in-depth-modules/) like this:

```
import * as moduleVar1 from "./variant/One.js";
import * as moduleVar2 from "./variant/Two.js";
import * as moduleVar3 from "./variant/Three.js";
```

Now, I e.g. select one of the loaded modules programmatically with a usual switch-case statement or similar. The selected module is saved via `module = moduleVar1` (or similar) in a variable.

Finally, I want to pass the module to another function:

```
continueFunction(module)
```

Now, **how do I document the parameter type in function** (here `continueFunction`), so that it specifies that **it accepts an ES6 module?**

I mean, `@param {Object}` would likely fit, but it is not really specific.

Answer (score 0):

You would use the tag of the exported type. For example if all modules were a `Number` then you would use `@param {Number}`.